# How to find difference between two dates in sql?

Tags: mysql, join

How can I display those records / customers details who stayed more then 2 days in hotel?
Table *Rooms* contains arrival and check out dates
Table *Customer* contains customer details. Both are connected via a primary key that is the room id.

*Rooms*

| arrival | checkout | roomid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/2/2004 | 2/3/2004 | 01 |
| 2/2/2004 | 2/3/2004 | 02 |

*Customer*

| cust name | room id |
| --- | --- |
| raj | 01 |
| rohan | 02 |

Output

| arrival | checkout | room id | cust name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/2/2004 | 2/3/2004 | 02 | rohan |

(ordering not mandatory, cust name can be 1st too)

Comment: What have you tried? [DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Answer (score 0):

A simple `inner join` can do the trick :

```
    select r.*, c.customerName
    from rooms r
    inner join customer c on c.roomid = r.roomid
    where datediff(checkout, arrival) > 1
```

Try it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/dOnB7W9_

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit weird that you have one customer per room (and not per room and time), but ok.

```
SELECT
  arrival,
  checkout,
  DATEDIFF(checkout, arrival) "number of days", -- leave this line out
  rooms.roomid "room id",
  customers.name "cust name"
FROM rooms
LEFT JOIN customers ON rooms.roomid = customers.roomid
WHERE DATEDIFF(checkout, arrival) >= 2;
```